# What is the policy on edits altering regional spellings?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

I have a few times during reviews encountered edits that change a US spelling to a UK spelling (or vice versa) such as initialize -> initialise. These are typically part of larger edits that correctly fix spelling errors.

What is the suggested policy for this? Should such edits be rejected to honor the original poster (which should be free to determine the precise English locale), or should they be accepted to include the correct fixes (implicitly accepting the UK ↔ US change)?

Comment: Personal preferences of the original author should be respected. Click on "Improve" and undo the UK/US changes, and keep the rest of the edit improvements.

Comment: If it's substantive enough without those changes, approve/improve depending on how much has been changed. If not, reject as too minor or with custom message.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23872/262755

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I see it, it just doesn't matter. Whether you spell it "color" or "colour" hardly defines your identity.

Granted, I will not edit posts just to "Americanize" the spellings of words. I don't think anyone should. I would reject those edits if they came up in the suggested edits queue, and I would suggest that you do the same.

However, when I rephrase entire sentences in a post, I will do this by retyping the entire sentence. It is much easier for me, I suppose because I'm a fast typist. And when I type something, I type it the way I would normally type it. So I'm sure that sometimes my edits change the spellings of words. It is inadvertent, not an act of imperialism. Since the edits are making otherwise useful changes, I think it is perfectly acceptable.

Similarly, if I'm adding additional content to an answer, I'm going to spell the words the way I normally would spell them. I'm not going to figure out whether the author uses British or American spellings and adapt. Again, I don't see anything wrong with this because the net effect is to improve the site's content.

This is just not something that needs an official "policy". If you disagree with an edit, you can roll it back wholesale, or you can revise specific portions of it. That's a judgment call. But I would implore you to avoid "noisy" edits one way or the other—either changing the spellings of words, or changing them back.