# What to do when a user targets your question history?

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm not sure why, but recently, I had a single user (who only shares one tag with me) go through my question history, and make very questionable edits to posts that are both new ([~1 month](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59187683/revisions)) and old ([~8 months](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55812228/revisions)).

The changes are rather minute and unnecessary -

[image]

Why is this user scanning through posts of mine from months ago and making minute grammar changes? This makes me feel targeted.

Note - I should add, I am all in favor of keeping high quality QA on Stack (look through my comment history -- I often write about this to new contributors). If this is justified, that is fine, but I would like to better understand ***why*** that is a necessary addition without an explanation to the OP on how to more accurately improve their questions in the future.

Comment: If they're under the rep threshold, perhaps to try and get rep for accepted edits?

Comment: @Larnu I don't think rep is a factor. ([link to revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55812228/revisions))

Comment: No, those won't be; but without knowing what post's revision, that was pure guess.

Comment: "*at the expense of the OP*"  - what do you mean by this?  I can see you feel these edits are "*minute and unnecessary*".  However the [Edit FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) clearly allows for sequential, small edits seeking to improve the post over time.  Does this violate the Edit FAQ?

Comment: That particular user has more than 72k edits under their belt. It’s possible they are not “targeting” you at all but actually trying to improve the posts. Have you pinged them and asked them about it?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know how @yivi. Again, I just found it odd that I sign into Stack Overflow with 3 notifications of a user editing my posts, some of which were nearly a year old. _If_ that is for the betterment of the community, I'm all about it! I just want to understand how that is beneficial, so that I can help others by doing the same thing / avoiding the scenario in the future.

Comment: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: Seems like fine edits to me, why do you think they're questionable? If users have >2K rep they can make minute changes without bothering reviewers, so that's fine

Comment: Also note that we have some users that are just way more involved in editing than others, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). The way you can do the same is simple: you see a post that objectively can be improved, you improve it, however minute. They might've just edited multiple of your old posts because they might've been searching for something you struggled with, and improved your questions while they were reading them to benefit people encountering the same problem.

Comment: That editor has made more than 100 edits in the last day, so your three posts represent less than 3% of the total edits. You're probably not being targeted.

Comment: For those reading -- what can I do to avoid 8+ downvotes? I was hoping this question would be useful for others, how can I edit it to be so?

Comment: @wundermahn Voting on Meta is different (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918/8239061)).  Votes can just mean disagreement and aren't necessarily indicative of quality; sometimes they're just disagreement with the presumed intent of the post.  Notice rep is unaffected.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarity. I'm certainly on a roll today with assumptions :) @SecretAgentMan

Comment: Shall you comment on my answer, wundermahn? You were keen to speak with me at one point.

Comment: I don't think so, I tried chatting a few times, but I think timing didn't work out. I don't have much more to say or add, is there something needed from me? @halfer

Comment: @wundermahn: no, I just assumed from your not replying that you remained unhappy about the edits. I am greatly pleased if this is not the case - for the most part, curation is done with the best of intentions here.

Comment: Nope, I understand much better now and, if I am being honest, am embarrassed that I misunderstood the situation. But, I can only use this as a learning tool, and hope to have more of these (and to approach them more maturely) in the future. @halfer

Comment: @wundermahn: no problem at all, thank you for wanting to learn `:=)`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, halfer does this. You aren't the first person to have noticed. :-)

He's [a prolific editor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer?tab=activity&sort=revisions), devoting a significant chunk of his time to improving posts on Stack Overflow. Anecdotally, I don't think I've ever seen him submit an edit that I didn't think was an improvement over the original.

halfer is, in my experience, particularly adept at removing "noise": trimming and rephrasing the author's words into something that is easier for others to read, without losing the original meaning. It looks like that's what he's done here, for your questions.

Rest assured that being "targeted" in this way (having your posts edited) is not a bad thing. It shouldn't be taken to assume that you've done anything wrong—just that someone saw a way they could improve the site and took the opportunity.

[Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing); this is one of the site's core principles. In this regard, and others, we share a lot of DNA with Wikipedia. Our primary goal, in fact, is to build a library of high-quality answers to the long tail of programming questions. Improving the presentation of individual questions is an important mechanism for achieving this goal. You might think that the edits are "minor"—why would anyone care if the wording of a question is a bit rambly?—but remember that Q&A aren't just here to help the original asker. They are maintained over the long term, where they help hundreds or thousands of people who have the same question and find the answers on our site via search engines.

> I would like to better understand ***why*** that is a necessary addition at the expense of the OP.

I would like to better understand why you think that edits are "at the expense of the OP". Edits *help* the OP, and they help everyone else.

Comment: that is exactly the type of response I was searching for. I appreciate the time you took to put together that response, and to attach and link some of the posts that you did. This is an excellent response. And, again for clarity, this was not an attack or knock -- _I just want to understand better_ *so that* _I can one day make a bigger impact on the community_. Thanks!

Comment: I always leave bits and pieces in my posts for Peter Mortensen to fix ...

Comment: @rene providing jobs, one post at a time, right?

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for the *Meta* question. I am always happy to justify my edits. Your chat invitation was also fine - I saw it, but since it did not contain a question I had nothing to reply to. If you would like to get in touch in the future, do please open a chat request, and put a question down, so I have something to respond to when I next log on.

### Why do we edit?

One of the themes I like to cover when talking about editing is what motivates me:

- Stack Overflow has helped me in my career, so I am paying it forward
- There is intrinsic satisfaction in improving the readability of posts for the benefit of future readers
- There is educational value in improving several posts from one contributor, as it gives them a chance to spot editing patterns (and to read edit reason messages), and thus their future material may not need as much editing

I am strongly in favour of view of Stack Overflow as "curated Q&A" rather than "technical discussion forum", and my edits can be seen in that light. As Cody says in his answer, we think of the site as being edited in much the same way as Wikipedia.

### The language of asking

The specific edit I made here falls into a category that has a bit of a back story. It's first worth noting that we like succinct, technical writing, so posts may be edited for that reason on its own.

However, I realised a couple of years ago that some forms of informal request on Stack Overflow had an interesting effect on me - I wondered if the language was deferential, to the degree that I (as the reader) was being placed upon a pedestal, exalted in some fashion, or even pleaded with. I found my experience of this phenomena to be interesting enough that I asked [a question about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

I got some interesting answers, but a piece of research [in this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366394/472495) was fascinating. It found that, all other things being equal, a nervous request of "please don't downvote" costs questions -0.6 in downvotes over the long run. This is intriguing for that specific case, since it suggests statistical evidence that the phrase is counterproductive on its own terms (as well as violating the requirement for technical writing).

I have developed a hunch that there is a wider set of politenesses - of which your screenshot is an example - that fall into a similar category. They are:

- not technical writing
- rather flowery and excessively polite
- transfer the agency of achieving something from the writer ("how can I") to the reader ("please help me out", "who is willing to rescue a noob?", "any help?")

There are some kinds of egregious pleading that stray into emotionally manipulative territory, though I would not say that applies in your case:

- here the writer may claim to be helpless or to have given up ("I am stuck", "I don't know what to do")
- the author may be willing to render themselves pathetic in order to obtain aid ("I have done my best", "I have been banging my head for hours", "this is so hard for me")

I should say that I am not making moral judgements here - the way people write is cultural and is not something they can change easily. But the trouble for writers is that the way people read is not easy to change either, and if readers experience a negative reaction to fawning (or the appearance of it) then we're doing both sides a favour by making the interaction more succinct. My suspicion is that readers are happier to help people who present as having similar psychological power, and conversely they are put off by writers who are disposed to worship their audience ("halp me, masters").

So, in your case, not only does the edit make it clearer and easier to read, but you might be less likely to acquire downvotes over the long term, especially if this change is replicated across your other questions.

### Further reading

- Question: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)
- Question: [Are mass edits ... from Q and A's acceptable for users with 2K Rep and more?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311530/are-mass-edits-removing-extensive-thanks-and-greeting-lines-from-q-and-as-acc)
- Answer: [What sorts of edits should editors make to posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341623/472495)

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: No worries @Cody `:-)`

Comment: References on US/UK spellings: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328787 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23872. I _think_ the consensus is maintain the editor's preference, but there are dissenting views: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268870.

Comment: I'm on board with using racially sensitive language, but "masters" in the context I quoted above probably meant "master craftsman" i.e. the head of a guild of skilled people, who was usually the best at a specific craft. I _think_ this is quite different to master/slave language, which I would be happy to see the back of in technology.

Comment: (The quoted text was from someone who struggled with English, and I wonder if it would have been counterproductive for me to tell them off for using racially insensitive language, especially if they might not have been White themselves. I take a moderate preference for correcting and improving my own language, but for the most part, I try to assume good intentions when others make different word choices).

Comment: Perhaps "halp me, wizards" would make a better example, getting the same point across while avoiding the word "master" in an ambiguous context.  Or "experts", "gurus", etc.  Paraphrasing an actual quote into something that avoids distraction for readers of this meta answer would avoid the need for those last two comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I seem to recall that the two comments above were indirectly addressed to an abusive and ill-motivated contributor in this comments section. I think their comments have now been deleted (by themselves or by a moderator), which has left these remarks looking rather out-of-context.

Comment: If you feel that a clarifying edit on this Meta answer would help though, go right ahead 

Comment: On 2nd thought, even "wizards" or "gurus" doesn't have quite the same tone of worshipfulness.  Respect and elevation, yes, but not to the same degree.  So I'm going to leave it.

Answer (score -22):

Changing "doesnt" to "doesn't" is not improving anyone's posts and not adding value. It does not add any readability, or clarify the author's intention.  Its just a waste of @halfer (and anyone else's) time. And though I dont feel personally threatened (yet) I'm really tired of being effectively online slow-stalked over the course of days/weeks.

*Its creepy.*

**Stop it.**

***If you followed someone around and behaved like this IRL, there would be a restraining order followed by jail time.***

So if you come across a post in normal use of the site and you see it needs editing, then edit it. But do not behave online toward other people any differently than you would IRL.

If its so important to you to make sure every contraction has an apostrophe, then lobby for a basic spellcheck/grammar check to be included instead of Edit Stalking and starting rollback battles.

Comment: Sorry, but if you feel that people volunteering their time to help improve content in this site is *creepy* then Stack Overflow is not the place for you? This site is a collaborative effort, and that means we expect and encourage our community to make edits like these.

Comment: And to put this in perspective: halfer is one of [a large number of prolific editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=year). A few of your posts were part of nearly 3.5k edits made this year, to date, by halfer alone. No one is targeting you or stalking you.

Comment: An analogy: the work editors do is a lot like street sweepers cleaning up around the public park and market place. You are the person complaining loudly about the street sweepers that dare to clean up a cigarette butt you tossed onto the ground and calling for restraining orders to keep them from doing their work. On Stack Overflow, cleaning up cigarette butts is valued, greatly. Learn to live with the street sweepers.

Comment: Someone has deleted the comments on here that cited two of the posts. One was a change of "dont" to "don't"  - an edit that does not improve the value or readability of the post. The other was a rolling back to an edit someone had made previously that left the post more ambiguous than what I had written.         Are you really going to defend a street sweeper thats not actually cleaning the street but making motions like they are, or that is smearing a small mess into a larger one and leaving it?  Thats the proper analogy here @MartijnPieters

Comment: Also keep in mind that when I saw a string of my posts getting edited I asked halfer to please stop. For someone supposed to be acting in a respectful, civil manner, that should have been enough of a request for him to have at least let up for a bit.  Instead he just got more aggressive with his defense and then started to make Trumpish statements about my "tone and violent language" in the above answer.  People should not behave that way toward each other. Just because you are donating your time to a charitable cause does not give you the right to be an ass toward those who you are helping.

Comment: halfer has been entirely polite and patient with you. I reviewed all the comments on this post and on the posts you recently tried to revert edit on (as a moderator I can review deleted comments), and nowhere would I classify his responses as “aggressive”. Your responses on the other hand have been belligerent and argumentative. If replacing `dont` with `don’t` is really meaningless then you could have **walked away and leave it be**.

Comment: I also can’t find any evidence of a rollback that made a post more ambiguous. There just three posts involved here, a question and two answers, so the claims that you are being stalked and followed around also seem to have no basis in fact.

Comment: He's been classic passive aggressive, and all of his long winded justification and crazy accusation comments have been deleted. Even my comments explaining rolling back edits have been deleted (the evidence you can't find). One of the comments on this very answer was to have him stop altering my personal history like some kind of gaslighting stalker, and lo and behold that gaslighting is exactly what's happening, even if by committee. Deleting history in ways that makes someone look foolish or discredits them is abusive, period.

Comment: After two unrelated things were edited I asked him to please stop. Should I waited until some other number ask him to stop?

Comment: I already stated quite clearly: **As a site moderator I can see all deleted comments**. There were no such comments. If you insist that there were, I'd be quite happy to make all comments public, here on this answer. On this site, **edits like these are the norm**. If you don't like such edits being made, our advice would be to not participate on this site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/353076/revisions - Why are even edit comments being deleted? Pretty sure that was where I asked him to stop after the 2nd unrelated edit.   The question that had edit rollbacks was one I asked about mongodb equivalent to MSSQL Temporal tables or change data capture. The question was probably my most recent question here but it no longer shows up on my profile or when searching... because it was deleted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400992/is-there-a-mongodb-equivalent-to-sql-insert-and-update-triggers-used-for-capturi). Thanks for linking that @halfer

Comment: @MartijnPieters - the second point I was making was that a person editing "dont" into "don't" is making a valueless contribution and just wasting their time. If they care so much about that level of correctness they should do it right and make a bot or ask the SO staff to add a feature to autofix it, or some other solution that takes the manual effort out of it.  Aren't the primary audience for SO people who automate tasks for a living?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged halfer about the deletion, it was [_automatically_ deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). The edit on that question you refer to was fine, the Microsoft product you refer to is even [tagged using that specific name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), the editor that made the change is the [top expert on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/topusers), rolling back those edits made your question **more** ambiguous.

Comment: The basic, bottom line premise is this: **posts on Stack Overflow are collaboratively edited, all edits involved here _improved_ the posts**. I am sorry you feel you were being stalked, but that is really not the case here.  Your own responses, both here and on the edited posts come over as overly hostile and aggressive; we require everyone to stick to our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and *assume good intent*. Even if there _was_ a problem with edits, your responses have only served to escalate the situation. In future, use flagging to handle problematic situations.